# Bad redirect on j_security_check form based authentication

Tags: jsp, jsf, web

After the user enters bad username/password I handle this by redirecting to error page. In my case error page is the same as login but I pass parameters wrongCredentials so I can render special block in my jsf page that displays wrong username/password message.
If user now enters a correct credentials **instead being redirected to source page he is redirected to */j_security_check with GET and gets 404 not found.**

What I found interesting is that when wrong credentials are entered the url in browser doesn't change to */login.xhtml?wrongCredentials=true but instead to */j_security_check but the rendered page is login with correct error message regarding bad credentials.

Here is my web.xml

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.xhtml?wrongCredentials=true</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Also here is login page form:

```
<form id="login_form" name="login_form" action="j_security_check" method="post">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" id="username" name="j_username" placeholder="Username"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="password" id="password" name="j_password" placeholder="Password"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="submit" value="login" class="btnBlue"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <p:panel rendered="${param['wrongCredentials'] != null}" styleClass="wrongPasswordPanel">
                                    <h:outputText value="Wrong username or password" styleClass="wrongPasswordTxt"/>
                                </p:panel>
                                <p:panel styleClass="forgotPasswordPanel">
                                    <h:outputText value="Forgot password? Please, contact " styleClass="wrongPasswordTxt"/><a href="mailto:support@support.com" class="wrongPasswordTxt">support@support.com</a>
                                </p:panel>
```

I have tried to implement a custom Filter to intercept */j_security_check on GET request but filter is loaded after j_security_check.

I am running WildFly10.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @André Yes I found the workaround that sorted the problem but didn't fix the root of it. I added custom Servlet filter that checked if there was a HTTP header entry Referer. If it was present and if it was set to j_security_check I would override it with the url to the homepage. This did the trick as redirect after successful login using jsecurity always redirects to the page provided in Referer header, this bypassed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got bad redirect error because I'm testing my app in https://localhost:8181/... and the server tries to redirect to https://0.0.0.0.0.0.0.1:8181/... which is supposed to be the IPv6 equivalent to 127.0.0.1 (look at the 'location' http response header).

The browser can't understand that IP and raises the error.

What I did as workaround was to test with my actual hostname instead of 'localhost', e.g. https://myhostname:8181/... in this case the server keeps the hostname in the location header instead of translating it to IPv6.